# Partial serialization on custom model

Tags: protobuf-net

Why ShouldSerialize pattern of partial serialization didn't work on custom RuntimeTypeModel? Is this work as designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are passing `false` to `applyDefaultBehaviour`, i.e.

```
var type = model.Add(typeof(SomeType), applyDefaultBehaviour: false);
```

in which case this question becomes "why, when I tell it not to apply any inbuilt patterns, does it not apply any inbuilt patterns?".

If you have elected to configure the model entirely manually, then *you must configure the model entirely manually*. In this case, something like:

```
type.AddField(1, "Foo").SetSpecified(
    typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("FooSpecified"), null);
```

(the first parameter is the "get" method, for use during serialization; the second parameter is the "set" method, for use during deserialization)

Comment: Thanks Marc. This is exactly i'm looking for. I have been missed this GetSpecified method.